# mapbox: GeolocateControl grouped with NavigationControl

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm completely new to mapbox and was just exploring api docs for a small project I'm currently working on.
One thing I want to do, but could not find anywhere (which is why I believe it may not be possible) is to put `GeolocateControl` together with `NavigationControl` button group.

Does anyone know whether it is actually doable?

What I have so far is two calls to `addControl`, which place one in the `top-left` - the other top right corner of the map.

```js
window.currentMap.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'top-left');
window.currentMap.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true
}));
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to adjust the CSS to move the two together so they appear grouped?

Comment: Thanks Andrew - I don't think that would work very well as depending on the screen size etc, these elements could potentially move etc. The `NavigationControl` element has rounded corners around it so even if I was to move the `GeolocateControl` close to the others, it would still look like a separate entity.

Comment: You can remove the rounded corners in CSS. It should be possible to do this by tweaking the CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can place both controls in the same corner. For instance, at opentrees.org, both are in the bottom right corner.

[image]

In your case, just change your last line to `}), 'top-left');`

If you need them to be even closer, or more "together" in some way, overriding the Mapbox-GL CSS (as Andrew suggested) is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks Steve - yes, I'm aware of the different positions available, but what I actually want to achieve is to have it grouped - not as a separate button - as I said, I don't think that's actually possible - just wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Visually grouped? Just tweak the CSS to remove the gap.